# Как убрать из переменной часть символов?

Tags: php

Как из переменной со значением `$phone="+375298542323"` убрать `+375` или `80`

Comment: Не пробовали справку почитать? [`str_replace('+358', '', $phone)`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.str-replace.php)

Comment: `str_replace('80','', string)`

Comment: @teran немножко не тот порядок у вас

Comment: @Oleksandr, да, поправил.

Comment: @Oleksandr, ваш способ я пробовал, но он не работает

Comment: @teran, ваш способ я пробовал, но он не работает

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Чтобы убрать в начале +375

```
$phone = preg_replace('/^\+375/', '', $phone);
```

Чтобы убрать в начале 80

```
$phone = preg_replace('/^80/', '', $phone);
```

А вот совместить их в одном регулярном выражении у меня пока не получается...

P.S. Может быть вот так

```
$phone = preg_replace('/^(\+375|80)/', '', $phone);
```

Comment: спасибо за ответ, по сути все должно работать, но у меня ничего не работает, данные с этой переменной сверяются с данными в ячейке БД и мне выдает что совпадений нет, но если ввожу без +375, то все работает

Comment: А базе данные хранятся в каком формате - число или строка? Может быть Вам нужно принудительно привести тип данных?

Comment: `$phone = preg_replace('/^(\+375|80)/', '', $phone);` спасибо этот вариант работает, но только частично, +375 не убирает, а 80 убирает

Comment: Я проверял в "песочнице" https://repl.it/ с PHP 7.0.8 (cli) (built: Jun 23 2016 23:39:14) ( NTS ) и там оба варианта обрабатываются нормально Вот ссылка на пример https://repl.it/Frpe/0

Comment: очень странно, ладно, буду разбираться, большое спасибо за ответ

Answer (score 2):

Можно пойти от обратного, зная что в номере телефона нужно "298542323", оставить именно эти цифры путем обреза строки с конца.

```
$phone="+375298542323";
$phone=substr($phone,-9);
```

Демо - https://eval.in/740668

Comment: спасибо за ответ, пользуюсь вашим вариантом, но отметить его как ответ не могу так как он не совсем по теме вопроса, у вас представлен вариант как обрезать строку взяв последние 9 цифр, а в вопросе была задача убрать конкретные значения, думаю вы меня поняли. Это просто для других пользователей которые хотели бы убрать конкретные значения.

Comment: Без проблем, задачу то можно решить по разному - это лишь вариант :).

Answer (score 1):

Если задача стоит "убрать первые несколько символов из номера телефона в зависимости от формата", тогда

```
$phone = preg_replace('/(^\+\d{3})|(^80)/', '', $phone);
```

Comment: спасибо за ответ, интересно то что если вводить с +375, то он не убирает, а если с 80, то все работает